# jquery tools vertical scrollable

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

i use this scroller http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html
I notice that it slide 3 div.item ...is possible chande to 2??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the demo, you'd see that it's is **really easy**. Change this part:

```
     <!-- first row -->
     <div class="item">

        <!-- image -->
        <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/_m.jpg" />

        <!-- title -->
        <h3>1. Barcelona Pavilion</h3>

        <!-- content -->
        <p>
           The Pavilion was not only a pioneer ...
        </p>

     </div>

     <!-- 2:nd and 3:rd rows -->
     <div class="item"> ... </div>
     <div class="item"> ... </div>

  </div>

  <!-- second element with another three rows (and so on) -->
  <div>
     ...
  </div>
```

To this:

```
     <!-- first row -->
     <div class="item">

        <!-- image -->
        <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/_m.jpg" />

        <!-- title -->
        <h3>1. Barcelona Pavilion</h3>

        <!-- content -->
        <p>
           The Pavilion was not only a pioneer ...
        </p>

     </div>

     <!-- 2:nd row -->
     <div class="item"> ... </div>

  </div>

  <!-- second element with another two rows (and so on) -->
  <div>
     ...
  </div>
```

Most of the changes are HTML comments. All you need to do is have one fewer `<div class="item">...</div>` in each set of items.